# how to move background-image on top of img tag on hover

Tags: css

Trying to solve that for many hours now without success.
I need to create css that works as following
requirement:http://s22.postimg.org/3xp5ut1gx/needed.jpg
and I must use the attached image.
overlay:https://i.stack.imgur.com/VNK86.png
I didn't find a way to do it without cutting the it, but I have to do it without cutting.
I know its somewhere in background-position area, but didn't manage to do so.
Will be very thankful for your help.
the code is very simple:

```
<div id="large-box">
        <div id="image"><img src="images/101512asiatodaysoftbank1_167x94.jpg" alt="stock-img" id="large-img" />
            <div id="play-btn"></div>
        </div>
      <p class="large-desc">Billionaries Love These 5 Stocks</p>
    </div>
```

so the css:

```
#large-box {
overflow: hidden;
height: 260px;
width: 293px;
position:relative;}

#image {
height: 230px;
position:relative;
}

#image img{
max-width:293px;
max-height:230px;
}

#play-btn {
background-image:url(../images/play.png);
background-repeat:no-repeat;
position:absolute;
bottom:75px;
left:10px;
width:101px;
height:43px;
z-index:10;
cursor: pointer;
/* display:none; */
}
```

Comment: What all have you tried until now?

Comment: tried putting it as background in separate div and position absoute to that div, but then when the position changes, the bottom (blue) button stuck above other objects on page (and I want it gone). I tried overflow:hidden, to div that holds the image, but that doesn't work from some reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you right, this is what you're looking for: http://codepen.io/BenMann/pen/hoyqD

However your image (with the play-buttons) is not completely transparent as it seems. It also does not have to be that large.. if you cropped it to contain only the two play buttons and no white-space you could reduce image-size!

Anyway, try tinkering with the `background-position: 0 -290px;` to make it fit perfectly.

**EDIT**

In case you need the hover to occur on the whole image, I just added some jQuery. Could also make it easier by just toggling a Class that sets the background-position.. but you get the idea.

Comment: thank you, I know that's it easily done with Jquery, but the task is to do that with css only AND not to change the image too.. that's where I'm stuck :/

Comment: Oh I see.. So what you can do is, have a div that is transparent and contains the play-buttons with the exact size of the image below and center the background-image inside of it. Then on hover of that div, you change the background-position accordingly. Example here: http://codepen.io/BenMann/pen/hoyqD